# Cannot Perform MenuSelect with PyWinAuto on Simple VB .NET Program (32-bit)

Tags: vb.net, python-3.x, menu, 32-bit, pywinauto

I created a simple VB .NET (32-bit) program.  The Menu for  the app has 3 menu items: "Exit", "New" , and "About".  I am trying to select the "New" Menu item but I receive an error.  The error is that there is no Menu.  I did print the Control Identifiers.  They are presented here.

```
Control Identifiers:
WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1 - 'b'MenuStrip1''   (L86, T109,    
R370, B133)

'b'MenuStrip1''
'b'MenuStrip1WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1''
'b'WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1''

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python Scripts\TestVBApp3.py", line 21, in <module>
app.MenuStrip.MenuSelect("New")
File "C:\Users\lyle.lacey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-   
32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py", line 1385, in   
MenuSelect
self.MenuItem(path, exact=exact).Select()
File "C:\Users\lyle.lacey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-
32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py", line 1337, in 
MenuItem
raise RuntimeError("There is no menu.")
RuntimeError: There is no menu.
```

Here is the Code (I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition):

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from time import sleep
import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\VBPrograms\\MenuStrip.exe"')

app.MenuStrip.Wait('ready')

app.MenuStrip.PrintControlIdentifiers()

app.MenuStrip.MenuSelect("New")

sleep(5)

app.MenuStrip.Close()
```

Note: I am using Python 3.5, pywinauto 0.5.4, Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (VB .NET for App).

Thanks for the assistance !!

-Lyle

[MenuStripApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en3FG.png)

Comment: Used Inspect.exe found I need to use UIA controls.  Any good examples of UIA control usage ?

Comment: UIA support is going to be supported only by the next release of pywinauto (ver 0.6) But the main work is already done and it's even merged to the master branch. You could give it a try by using the latest master sources (https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto)